# Create a list of name from onclick selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a list of item based on multiple selection.
I have a combobox that create (when you choose on option) the url of an image starting from the value of the option.

```
<span>
<select id="menu1">
<option value="xx1" id="xx1">Name of selection 1</option>
<option value="xx2" id="xx2">Name of selection 2</option>
<option value="xx3" id="xx3">Name of selection 3</option>
<option value="xx4" id="xx4">Name of selection 4</option>
</select>
</span>

<span class="first">
<img id="scelta1" src="" alt="Prima Scelta">
</span>

function setCard1() {
var img = document.getElementById("scelta1");
img.src = 'immagini/collezionabili/' + this.value + '.png';
return false;}
document.getElementById("menu1").onchange = setCard1;
```

I need to create a list based on the chooses from images on click. Something like: click on the img, add this.value in "spot" 1 of the list, choose another img, add this.value in "spot" 2 and so on. 
How can I achieve this?

EDIT: 
The dropdown are 3, all similar and with a similar function for each. "Spot" it's a row in a table, so, I need to put the "this.value" into a table like:

```
<table id="mazzo">
<tr><td id="pick01">"first onclick choice here"</td></tr>
<tr><td id="pick02">"second onclick choice here"</td></tr>
<tr><td id="pick03">"third onclick choice here"</td></tr>
<tr><td id="pick04">"forth first onclick choice here"</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm new to JS, I need to create a table "populated" onclick with the value of the <option>  taken from the image created with the function above. I have some problem to explain it in english!

Comment: Can you specify what is "spot" ? How many images are there ? @Flaivo

Comment: "Spot" In my case it's a row in a table, so: first choice in the first row, second choice in second row etc etc. The function create only one image, the choice it's from 3 similar combobox with a function for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace setCard1 function with below code :

```
function setCard1() {
var img = document.getElementById("scelta1");
img.src = 'immagini/collezionabili/' + this.value + '.png';


//**Change below line** 

 var myTable=document.getElementById("tableBody");

 var noOfChoices = myTable.rows.length+1;
 var selectedImage = "<tr><td id='pick'"+noOfChoices+">"+noOfChoices+" choice here</td></tr></tr>";
//Add a row to table
myTable.append(selectedImage);

return false;}
```

Change your table to as below

```
<table id="mazzo">
<tbody id="tableBody">
<tr><td id="pick01">"first onclick choice here"</td></tr>
<tr><td id="pick02">"second onclick choice here"</td></tr>
<tr><td id="pick03">"third onclick choice here"</td></tr>
<tr><td id="pick04">"forth first onclick choice here"</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And check now

Comment: It just don't work, this function print: <tr><td id='pick'2>2 choice here</td></tr></tr><tr>